# asp:ListView create an Case condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

Hello find below my code.

I am trying to create a webpart for sharepoint where I can bind multiple type of items in a slider.

I have 2 types  an **Image** or a **Video**

And each type has different tag and formatting. so I wont be able to just bind value into tags. my question is how can I create like a "SwiCh case" inside the listview.

if type = image  --> bind a tag else bind the second tag.

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvA">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div class="slider">
            <ul class="bxslider">
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder" />
            </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <!-- "tag A" -->
            <video width="320" height="260" controls>
                <source src="xyz" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
        </li>
        <li>
            <!-- "tag B" -->
            <img src="abc" />
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: How can you tell if type is image? With that condition?

Comment: the item bonded from code behind contain a column that tell if its type image or video

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

- Have a `<asp:PlaceHolder>` for the **Video** and the **Image** type.
- Put a condition in the `Visible` attribute for each `<asp:PlaceHolder>`. Change the condition suitable to your project.

Code here:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("type") == "video" %>'>
        <li>
            <video width="320" height="260" controls>
                <source src="xyz" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
        </li>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("type") == "image" %>'>
        <li>
            <img src="abc" />
        </li>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**Update**: You correctly pointed out that possible errors might occur during runtime. If you are not able to avoid these errors by adding additional checks on your data, there a second alternative, but it has some limitations.

The solution is to render each item in code behind. For each scenario you create a function that returns HTML:

```
protected string RenderVideo(System.Data.DataRow dr)
{
    // Get values from the current DataRow
    string path = dr["path"].ToString();

    // Create the appropriate markup for your video
    return "<video>" + "</video>"; 
}

protected string RenderPhoto(System.Data.DataRow dr)
{
    // Get values from the current DataRow
    string path = dr["path"].ToString();

    // Create the appropriate markup for your video
    return "<img src='' alt='' />";
}
```

Each of the functions has a `DataRow` as a parameter. Then all you need to is to call each function when needed with the current `DataRow`. The current `DataRow` can be accessed by `((System.Data.DataRowView)GetDataItem()).Row`.

In the following example I use an inline if to call the correct function.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%#(Eval("type") == "video" ? RenderVideo(((System.Data.DataRowView)GetDataItem()).Row) : RenderPhoto(((System.Data.DataRowView)GetDataItem()).Row)) %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**Alternative**: If you have more than two scenarios the above use of inline if is inefficient. You can do the following which practically is the same but more practical to maintain.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%#(Eval("type") == "video" ? RenderVideo(((System.Data.DataRowView)GetDataItem()).Row) : "") %>
    <%#(Eval("type") == "photo" ? RenderPhoto(((System.Data.DataRowView)GetDataItem()).Row) : "") %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

The limitation on this approach is that you cannot have ASP controls on each item.

Comment: but will this cause an error on binding , since visible even the the src in img and video is a variable that will be bonded from code behind and the type in video as well.

Comment: That is true, but you could put some code that checks the values and avoid the errors. I posted a second answer that does not have this problem. I hope this will help you.